# Java HTML parser including script tags and a LineNumberReader

Tags: java, html

I extended the class `HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback` to get the tags, the comments and the corresponding line number of a html file.

```
FileReader inputStreamReader = new FileReader( modelFile );
lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader( inputStreamReader );
delegator.parse( lineNumberReader, this, true );
```

Normally it works but if the html document contains a script tag, `handleError()` is called with the error message `javascript.unsupported ? ? ?`.
So far so good, I get the content of the script tag as comment but the line number reader returns the line number of `</html>`; instead of `</script>`.

How is it possible to get the correct line number?

Example document:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            int a;
            function abc () {
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks, 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Derive your own ScriptPatchingReader class from LineNumberReader.

In that class watch out for `<script` and then place a newlines only till `</script>`, saving the script body with line number. Afterwards do with the scripts what you want.
You might want to store whether it was in the `<head>` part or the `<body>`.

BTW FileReader uses the current platform encoding. If having a fixed encoding like UTF-8:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(modelFile), "UTF-8");
```